# Vim Omnicomplete Pattern not found (Python)

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I read that omnicompletion should work 'out of the box' but it doesn't, and I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

I compiled the latest version of vim and it shows "+python":

```
user$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 16 2013 11:22:56)
MacOS X (unix) version
Compiled by user@computer.local
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv -cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input -iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm -multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Users/user/Software/vim/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim       -lm -lncurses  -framework Cocoa     -framework Python
```

I cleared out my .vimrc to just leave:

```
" Automatic reloading of .vimrc
autocmd! bufwritepost .vimrc source %

filetype plugin on
```

and my ~/.vim/ directory is just

```
autoload/pythoncomplete.vim
```

which I downloaded from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542

and the following command returns:

```
:echo &omnifunc
pythoncomplete#Complete
```

which seems to be fine. But every time I do control-xo on the following test.py file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import numpy
numpy.r
```

either after typing "num" or "numpy.r" I get

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

Is there a problem with my installation? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**: Following the suggestion from TankorSmash about installing python-mode, I can get "num" to complete to "numpy" but not "numpy.r" to complete to anything.

Here is my new .vimrc file:

```
" Automatic reloading of .vimrc
autocmd! bufwritepost .vimrc source %

" Pathogen load
filetype off

call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

and my .vim directory tree:

```
.vim
    autoload
        pathogen.vim
        pythoncomplete.vim
    bundle
        python-mode
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest to use jedi-vim instead of pythoncomplete: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* any third party completion script to be able to complete Python.

I don't have one (the only Python-specific script I have is a short ftplugin) and these are the suggestions I get when I hit `<C-x><C-o>` after `numpy.` and `numpy.arc`…

[image: numpy.]

[image: numpy.arc]

Since you appear to be on Mac OS X, you *really* shouldn't compile Vim yourself. Installing the latest MacVim snapshot is the best way to run Vim on a Mac and I'm fairly certain you'd get the same suggestions as on this Linux machine out of the box.

***edit***

I just tested the same code on an old MacVim (snapshot 53) on my wife's bare bones iMac (python 2.5) and I got more or less the same suggestions (485 vs 551).

Comment: That got it working! I wonder why it works for macvim and not for vim in the iTerm terminal. Anyway, thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: If that's what you use, the default Vim (`/usr/bin/vim`) is a small build that lacks a bunch of useful things. It is *recommended* to install a proper build if you want to make it your workhorse. Since you want to work in a terminal emulator, know that MacVim can be executed in your shell: 1. place the `mvim` script that comes with MacVim somewhere in your `$PATH`, 2. do `$ mvim -v` to run MacVim in iTerm.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I've learned about the GUI-type macvim, I might end up using that. I suppose that to fully compile a useful vim, one also needs to install things from "runtime" etc at http://www.vim.org/download.php, which I didn't notice before (though I don't intend to try that). Thanks again!